# How to select a button beside the gradient filter

Tags: html, css, gradient

I met a project that set the gradient filter to whole web page.
So I have implemented the filter like this.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdc3Lh/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <button class="tag">Featured</button>
   <div id="grad1">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(red, yellow); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.container {
   border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
}
.tag {
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   background-color: #92AD40;
   padding: 5px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

But the problem is button is not selectable in this case.
I have no sense how to make the button work.
How can I make button selectable and also show gradient above the button?

Finally UI should look like this.
[image]

Comment: Change `.tag {z-index: 0;}` to `.tag {z-index: 1;}`  The problem is the gradient is on top of the button.

Comment: I also tried that but If so, I cannot see gradient on button area, please see http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdc3Lh/2/

Comment: If you would like a gradient also on the button the button should have its own gradient background, or be transparent. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wed5ntfo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its seems you are looking for `pointer-events: none;`

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdc3Lh/5/

Comment: @Ismail Farooq How `pointer-events: none;` is the good solution. Because of if any `clickable element` inside the `#grad1` it will be `none clickable`. Until set the `pointer-events: default;` for inside `element`. check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdc3Lh/6/

Comment: you are right `pointer-events: auto;` for the child element will fix here it is http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdc3Lh/7/

Answer (score 0):

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdc3Lh/1/). You have two issue 1. set `button` `attribute` `type="button"` and 2. `.tag` `z-index` should be `1`. Because your `button` is `absolute` position.

**UPDATE**

I Update the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6tdc3Lh/4/). I think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but your fiddle changed ui, there should be gradient effect on button, if z-index is bigger gradient is not shown,

Comment: Thanks, but what I exactly looking for was found byIsmail Farooq

Answer (score 0):

a `</div>` tag is missing.
At the end of ur code.

Ur container isnt closing, so your button cant‘t be clicked.

Try to add just another closing tag.

Comment: I have changed, but that's typo, my problem is logic problem